# Logarithmic Least Square Method on Matlab

Tags: matlab, logarithm, least-squares, data-fitting

How can I use this function `y=(a*x)./(b+x)` to approximate this data
`x = [1.5 4 5 8 12 16 17]`, `y = [1.6 2.6 2.4 3.2 3.4 3.6 3.4]` with the least square method using matlab?

I used logarithms and got `log(y)=log(a*x)-log(b+x)`. The result is not in the form `y = a*x + b` that I need it to be. `a` it's not multiplied with `x`,as it should be,but it's being added to it,because `log(y)=log(a)+log(x)-log(b)`. So I don't know what to do next. I know the code to do `y=b*x.^a` and `y=b*exp.(x*a)`, but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Um, I think its time to go back to algebra 1. log(b+x) is not the same as log(b). You cannot solve this using logs, at least not as you have tried.

As long as you are willing to play fast and loose with error structure (even if you don't know what that means, it can still be important) then suppose you invert things?

```
1/y = (b+x)/(ax) = b/(ax) + 1/a
```

Transform the problem, so that

```
c = b/a
d = 1/a
u = 1/x
v = 1/y
```

Now we have

```
v = cu + d
```

Solve this linear regression problem, then recover a and b from c and d.

In MATLAB, its simple.

```
x = [1.5 4 5 8 12 16 17];
y = [1.6 2.6 2.4 3.2 3.4 3.6 3.4];

u = 1./x;
c_d = polyfit(u,1./y,1)
c = c_d(1);
d = c_d(2);

a = 1./d
a =
          3.90554889035516

b = c*a
b =
          2.19394529536478
```

And plot the results of the fit.

```
ezplot(@(x) a.*x./(b+x),[1.5 17])
hold on
plot(x,y,'ro')
```

[image]